# Elasticsearch conditional sort on date field

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to sort an Elastic Search query result on a date field, `registeredAt`. However, `registeredAt` doesn't exist in all documents returned. In that case, I would want the sort to look for the date on an alternative field, `invitedAt`.

If we have 3 hits which look like this:

```
    hits = [
    {
       id: 'hit2'
       registeredAt: '2021-06-01T23:00:00.000Z',
       invitedAt: '2021-05-31T23:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
       id: 'hit3'
       invitedAt: '2021-05-31T23:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
       id: 'hit1'
       invitedAt: '2021-06-04T23:00:00.000Z'
    },
    
    ],
```

then I would want the sort to return them in order from most recent to least recent: `[hit1, hit2, hit3]`.
In each document, the sort script should look for the `registeredAt` field and take that date as the sort value and, if that field does not exist, look at the value for `invitedAt` and take that as the sort value.
In that sense, `hit1` does not have a `registeredAt` and has the most recent date for `invitedAt` and, as such, should come first. `hit2` has a `registeredAt` field and the date for that field is more recent than the `invitedAt` date of `hit3` (which doesn't have a `registeredAt` field.

I have written the query as such:

```js
client.search({
        index: 'users',
        track_total_hits: true,
        sort: {
        _script: {
          type: 'number',
          script: {
            lang: 'painless',
            source:
              "if (!doc.containsKey('registeredAt') || doc['registeredAt'].empty) { return doc['invitedAt'].value; } else { return doc['registeredAt'].value }",
          },
          order: 'desc',
        },
      },
        body: {
          from: skip,
          size: limit,
          query: {...},
        },
      })
```

The query runs without errors but the sorting does not work and the documents are returned in the order that they were indexed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `registeredAt` and `invitedAt`  are `date` in the mapping.
This query should work. What I added is calling `.getMillis()` after getting the value.

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            if (!doc.containsKey('registeredAt') || doc['registeredAt'].empty) { 
              return doc['invitedAt'].value.getMillis();
              
            } 
            else { 
              return doc['registeredAt'].value.getMillis();
            }
          """
        },
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit: `.getMillis()` is depricated in version 7.x. `.toInstant().toEpochMilli()` should be used instead.

This is the query:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            if (!doc.containsKey('registeredAt') || doc['registeredAt'].empty) { 
              return doc['invitedAt'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
              
            } 
            else { 
              return doc['registeredAt'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
            }
          """
        },
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```